# Using moment js how do display only the time from a UTC timestamp?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a timestamp `2016-09-14T10:44:55.027Z` and I would like to only display the `10:44:55` part but I'm not completely sure how. I have access to the moment library but not sure how to pass this into moment and format it, also how could I add AM or PM?

```
moment("2016-09-14T10:44:55.027Z").format('hh:mm:ss')
```

seems to output 11:44:55?

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eemfu0ym/

Comment: UTC timestamps are generally converted to the local timezone when parsed through the Date constructor in javascript, which is why it adds an hour.

Comment: `moment("2016-09-14T10:44:55.027Z").utc().format('hh:mm:ss')`. To get an output with `AM/PM` use `.format("LTS")` (only available in versions >= 2.8.4)

Comment: Or without an entire library -> `"2016-09-14T10:44:55.027Z".match(/T(.*?)\./)[1]`

Comment: moment(value).locale('en').format(/* ... */);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your input contains the `Z` suffix, that means the input value is in UTC.  However, you're passing it into the default moment constructor, which is *local time*, thus a conversion occurs.

To keep it in UTC, the simplest way is to just obtain the moment object in UTC mode to begin with.

```
var m = moment.utc("2016-09-14T10:44:55.027Z")
```

Once you have that, you can format it however you like:

```
m.format('HH:mm:ss')   // 24-hour clock time
m.format('hh:mm:ss A') // 12-hour time with meridiem (AM/PM)
```

See the [moment formatting docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for other options.  Do note that tokens are case sensitive.